# It does not recognize the route /greeting

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask, I'm trying to do a rest api, but when creating my route it doesn't recognize it for me.
I have imported flask and python 3.8.

```
from products import products
from flask import Flask

@app.route('/greeting')
def greeting():
return 'hi'


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, port=4000)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the instance of the Flask class

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

A minimal Flask application looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/greeting')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=4000)
```

Now you could see it running at:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

Access the greeting as  http://127.0.0.1:4000/greeting

For more info read [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)

Comment: Thanks,very much

Comment: Glad it helped you , consider upvote/accepting answer :)